# Create a Google Load Balancer with fixed IP to Istio Ingress Gateway in GKE

Tags: load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I Have a Google GKE with 2 nodes and Istio installed.

It created automatically 2 load balancers with ephemeral IPs. I use one of them in CloudDNS (HTTPS) to redirect DNS to one of the ingress-gateways.

When I need to recreate the cluster there will be another Istio with another ips. Then, I have to change the ip in cloudDNS. It takes some minutes to this change to take effect.

I have to eliminate these minutes. For that we want to create a load balancer with a fixed IP. This ip will be fixed in CloudDNS. This way, when I need to recreate the cluster I will change load balancer to point to the new cluster istio ingress gateway. The changes wil take effect immediately.

Then, my question is: How can I create a load balancer with a fixed IP to my Istio ingress gateways?

I tried several combinations of TCP load balancer/HTTPS Load Balancer with a fixed IP pointing to the LB created to istio-ingressgateways but when I put the Fixed IP in Cloud DNS it does not work.

Comment: if you are using the istio add on, I don't believe this is possible. the istio add on is a managed add on, any of the automatically created resources can't be changed. The last time I checked this was a few months ago though, so there may have been some changes, or an alpha feature. To my knowledge, you simply can't do it and would need to install an unmanaged istio rather than using the GKE add on

Comment: My Istio is a custom installation.

Comment: In that case, your istio ingressgateway should be a service type load balancer, which you can assign a static IP to through the field `spec.loadBalancerIP`. just make sure the up has been reserved first